# How to use external image inside phonegap/jquerymobile app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap/jquery-mobile test application (I'm new in this technologies) for android and I want show inside my app an image stored on internet site. During app startup in avd I receive this notification when put in my index.html this element:

```
<img src="http://www.comolakeboats.it/images/stories/boats/gommone_12_150x100.jpg" width="120px;" />
```

> Application Error - the connection to the server was unsuccessfull (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

On log.cat I can see this error:

> E/DroidGap(337): DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient

I already checked connection both from browser and inside my application with an external link and in both case I can reach internet site.

What I'm missing? Exists a solution (maybe the same) suitable for Iphone,too?

This is my code:

```
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="home_it"> 
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" id="it">
            <h1>TEST</h1> 
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="tel://+3933333333">Tel:+3933333333</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="mailto:info@test.it?subject=Info">Email</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </div> 
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-c"><!--  ui-body-b">-->  
                <p>Some text</p>
                <button id="my_list_button">Mostra</button>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="content"  class="ui-body">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="my_list">
                <li data-role="list-divider">My list</li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.comolakeboats.it" rel="external">
                        <img src="http://www.comolakeboats.it/images/stories/boats/gommone_12_150x100.jpg" width="120px;" />
                        <h3>title foo foo</h3>
                        <p style="color:red">foo foo foo foo</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
                    <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home">&#160;</a></li>    
                    <li><a id="exit-app" data-icon="back">&#160;</a></li>    
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div> 


</body>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: A few notes that might help you:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you actually update the phonegap's whitelist? that tells the app which URLs it's allowed to access. You can also add a * to it, [as described here](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/11/22/phonegap-gotcha-error-whitelist-rejection/)

Hope this helps

Comment: there's no whitelist for Phonegap on Android, AFAIK.

Comment: That is incorrect. It is in the /res/xml/phonegap.xml file. That file might not exist by default (especially in apps created with older versions of PhoneGap), but the whitelist does. Also it differs from iOS in syntax. It more along the lines of `<phonegap><access origin="http://*.phonegap.com"/></phonegap>`.

Comment: I think it should be my problem: I try using a localhost url and my app start without problem (and in phonegap.xml there is this an origin relative to 127.0.0.1*). 
I try to adding an external origin but for now Im alwyas KO

Comment: No way, I put into  white list my external origin but the emualtor seems to not consider it

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. My problem was caused by 2 conditions: 
1) not white list setting
2) connection troguht proxy: it seems phonegap is unable to solve proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you put higher values in defaultactivity:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 60000);
```

It won't time out but it will take ages for your app to run...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the most simple you can do is download the image and add it to your project. In that case just make the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag reference the image path inside your project.

Comment: No because my next step is try to retrieve some data using a ajax remote call, so I will know only at runtime what infos show and what image show. I haven't control on image

Comment: If the image is variable, you could download it and write it to a fixed local path in your device. I don't know how you could do this in PhoneGap, but it's only an idea and I could not find any other solution. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

A few notes that might help you:

- the index.html has to be a full html document  ...
- you have to set the permissions to use the internet, in AndroidManifest.xml
- the test device has to have an internet connection (try opening the image url on the device browser first).

Comment: As I say, I did exactly the same check. And they are all OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have set the whitelist in my cordova.xml to ".*" but it still displays the same error so I tried looking for other solutions and found this out:

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_build_viewebclient_timeout_error_on_android_device

His solution was to redirect the page from the index.html to a main page. I don't know why it worked for me but happy that it did. If you would see any problem doing this work around please do comment, I don't want to encounter other major problems in the future because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Finally i find the reason is "Content-Security-Policy" setting in head of the html!. You can simply remove the line like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```