# E/DroidGap(21383): DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient

Tags: android, cordova, webkit, webviewclient

I use phonegap 1.3.0 to develop mobile application.
when i click one button that will invoke my plugin to invoke a js function, after about 20s, countered the error: "E/DroidGap(21383): DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient" in eclipse log console.
and the emulator alert a dialog, show error message : The connection to the server was unsuccessful.(javascript:showProcessBar(1))
How can I fix the error? thanks!

There are some details below to complement my question.
when I invoke js function in phonegap plugin. there must will show error message in logcat:"E/DroidGap(21383): DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient" .

I find the code that generate the error. just below:

```
private void loadUrlIntoView(final String url) {
    if (!url.startsWith("javascript:")) {
        LOG.d(TAG, "DroidGap.loadUrl(%s)", url);
    }

    this.url = url;
    if (this.baseUrl == null) {
        int i = url.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (i > 0) {
            this.baseUrl = url.substring(0, i+1);
        }
        else {
            this.baseUrl = this.url + "/";
        }
    }
    if (!url.startsWith("javascript:")) {
        LOG.d(TAG, "DroidGap: url=%s baseUrl=%s", url, baseUrl);
    }

    // Load URL on UI thread
    final DroidGap me = this;
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // Init web view if not already done
            if (me.appView == null) {
                me.init();
            }

            // Handle activity parameters
            me.handleActivityParameters();

            // Track URLs loaded instead of using appView history
            me.urls.push(url);
            me.appView.clearHistory();

            // Create callback server and plugin manager
            if (me.callbackServer == null) {
                me.callbackServer = new CallbackServer();
                me.callbackServer.init(url);
            }
            else {
                me.callbackServer.reinit(url);
            }
            if (me.pluginManager == null) {
                me.pluginManager = new PluginManager(me.appView, me);        
            }
            else {
                me.pluginManager.reinit();
            }

            // If loadingDialog property, then show the App loading dialog for first page of app
            String loading = null;
            if (me.urls.size() == 1) {
                loading = me.getStringProperty("loadingDialog", null);
            }
            else {
                loading = me.getStringProperty("loadingPageDialog", null);                  
            }
            if (loading != null) {

                String title = "";
                String message = "Loading Application...";

                if (loading.length() > 0) {
                    int comma = loading.indexOf(',');
                    if (comma > 0) {
                        title = loading.substring(0, comma);
                        message = loading.substring(comma+1);
                    }
                    else {
                        title = "";
                        message = loading;
                    }
                }
                me.spinnerStart(title, message);
            }

            // Create a timeout timer for loadUrl
            final int currentLoadUrlTimeout = me.loadUrlTimeout;
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        synchronized(this) {
                            wait(me.loadUrlTimeoutValue);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // If timeout, then stop loading and handle error
                    if (me.loadUrlTimeout == currentLoadUrlTimeout) {
                        me.appView.stopLoading();
                        LOG.e(TAG, "DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient");
                        //me.webViewClient.onReceivedError(me.appView, -6, "The connection to the server was unsuccessful.", url);
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
            me.appView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });
}
```

I comment the line : me.webViewClient.onReceivedError(me.appView, -6, "The connection to the server was unsuccessful.", url); because it will alert a dialog to terminate my program.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339136/how-to-use-external-image-inside-phonegap-jquerymobile-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android enforces a timeout when loading URLs in a webview.

check out this link, (it doesn't really pertain to JQM) , but phonegap android
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem explains itself.. when there's a `time out` response in any PhoneGap call to an external URL it throws that error.

You can you this HTML5 feature to check the internet connection:

```
navigator.onLine;
```

You can see it working here: http://html5demos.com/nav-online

Answer (score 0):

super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue",60000);

Place this line in java code in Activity